# Why is the ReadFromEnumerable method not working? ML.NET

Tags: c#, ml.net

I'm trying to recreate the following sample https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/samples/Microsoft.ML.Samples/Dynamic/SsaSpikeDetectorTransform.cs
but I keep getting an error that DataOperations doesn't contain a definition for the ReadFromEnumerable method.
I also get an error that the CreateEnumerable method doesn't exist, but I suspect it relates to the ReadFromEnumerable error.

I've copied the entire namespaces and code in case I might have missed out something, but the error still occurs.

Read From Enumerable method

```
var ml = new MLContext();

//Generate sample series data with a recurring pattern and a spike within the pattern
  const int SeasonalitySize = 5;
  const int TrainingSeasons = 3;
  const int TrainingSize = SeasonalitySize * TrainingSeasons;
  var data = new List<SsaSpikeData>();
  for (int i = 0; i < TrainingSeasons; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < SeasonalitySize; j++)
          data.Add(new SsaSpikeData(j));

//This is a spike
  data.Add(new SsaSpikeData(100));
  for (int i = 0; i < SeasonalitySize; i++)
      data.Add(new SsaSpikeData(i));

// Convert data to IDataView.
var dataView = ml.Data.ReadFromEnumerable(data); //This is where the error occurs
```

CreateEnumerable Method

```
var predictionColumn = ml.CreateEnumerable<SsaSpikePrediction>(transformedData, reuseRowObject: false);
```

Comment: those might be extensions which require to add additional external references to the project, or a version mismatch. have a look at the project file / build file of the sample.

Comment: Do you have this using:

using Microsoft.ML.Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like dlatikay said, it was a version mismatch.
The sample I provided is from a version that's still in preview. 
For ML.NET 0.9.0 and older versions, you need to use CreateStreamingDataView.
To get ReadFromEnumerable and CreateEnumerable working, you can download the ML.NET 0.10.0 and 0.11.0 preview packages from here https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-core/package/nuget/Microsoft.ML/0.11.0-preview-27404-5